# Grouping a set of instances that almost match in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a set of properties which I am grabbing in my controller like this --

```
def index
  @properties = Property.all
  @properties = @properties.where("bedrooms = ?", params[:bedrooms])            if params[:bedrooms].present?
  @properties = @properties.text_search(params[:query])                         if params[:query].present?
  @properties = @properties.area_search(params[:area])                          if params[:area].present?
  @properties = @properties.where("month_available = ?", params[:availability]) if params[:availability].present?
  @properties = @properties.where("vacancy_status = ?", params[:now])           if params[:now].present?
end
```

I am displaying them in my view through rendering a partial, now here's my issue --

The view is of all properties meeting the above search criteria, sometimes this is 100+ properties.  Some of these properties have almost identical addresses since they are in the same building but have different unit numbers, unfortunately, the unit number is attached to the :street_address attribute in my DB (ex. 123 Main Street B).  When I am displaying the search results, I need to only display the address once (ex. 123 Main Street) instead of each instance of that address (which can be up to 40 times).  I have to continue to show all of the other properties that meet the search criteria, it is not as if I am only pulling the data for a single address.  Typically I am pulling the data for all properties with 4 bedrooms or something like that.

Side note: I am doing this with over 400 properties that are being pulled from a database, so I can't hard code in an address, I need the solution to be dynamic, which has been the sticking point for me in getting to a solution.  Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: What about full-text search? You didn't specify what database you're using, but Postgres and MySQL both have methods for doing this.

Comment: What database are you using?  Postgres offers pattern matching queries out of the box:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: I am using Postgres - I am already using some full text searching through the built in Postgres queries, but my issue is trying to figure out how to only display one of the properties at 123 Main Street instead of all 10.

Comment: You mean like `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Do your properties always have the format: Address ... Letter?

Comment: Maybe I completely missed the mark in my question. I'm going to make an edit.

Comment: Do the addresses follow any sort of standard format? Is the unit number always represented in a certain way? For example, do they always follow a pattern like 1234 Main St. #526 or 1234 Main St. Ste 526?

Comment: @coenwolf - yes they do. It is always number + street name + street type (ave, street, lane, etc...) + suite or apartment number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this example a shot:
(I am grouping by address except for the last character, and stripping. You can enhance the grouping based on your knowledge of how properties are listed)

```
addresses = ["123 main st. A", "123 main st. J", "124 Main street", "123 main st."]

# define how properties are grouped here; don't worry about "weird" groups; they'll only contain one value and we'll get rid of it in the next line
map = addresses.group_by { |a| a[0..-2].strip }
(addresses - map.reject { |k,v| v.length < 2 }.values.flatten).collect { |k| { k => map[k] || k } }

=> [{"124 Main street"=>"124 Main street"},
 {"123 main st."=>["123 main st. A", "123 main st. J"]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just simple text matching the beginning of the address string you can use [SQL LIKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29#LIKE):

```
@properties.where("address LIKE ?", "#{params[:address]}%")
```

Here I'm using the `%` wild card to tell it SQL to match address with anything after it, so:

```
"123 Main St" will match "123 Main St and anything here"
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the property once there is an easy way. How about taking the first 7 (or whatever fits your needs) characters. This way house number + part of the street address match and you are using only the first database hit for this match. You could also take all results, take the first 7 characters and then put them into an array and work with that.

When added to the array just do:

```
    myarray = myarray.uniq
```

Now you have every address once.